# 'User' isn't a function. Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'User'.dartinvocation_of_non_func

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UXCp.png)[The name 'User' is defined in the libraries 'package:brew_crew/models/user.dart' and 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.dartambiguous_import
'User' isn't a function.
Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'User'.dartinvocation_of_non_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDKTi.png)

Answer (score 1):

`User` is defined in `brew_crew` models and in `firebase_auth` package.

Change

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

to

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
```

and use it as `auth.FirebaseAuth`, `auth.User`, `auth.UserCredential` etc.